# docker cp command hangs in mesosphere

Tags: docker, mesosphere, dcos

Issue : 
While copying a text file from DC/OS slave node to the docker container running , the docker cp command hangs .

When we terminate it after few minutes , the docker ps -a also starts hanging .

NOTE : rest of the commands like docker images , docker inspect , docker version work fine.

Comment: Can you provide some info about the cluster environment (where is it running, which docker version, which filesystem permissions)

Comment: DC/OS version : 1.9   Docker version : 1.12